# The issue in implementing google one-tap login on Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, google-one-tap

How can i apply google one tap login on my Shopify theme
i have try this code

```
window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: 'client_id',
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
}
function handleCredentialResponse(res) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: res,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

but when i run simple script is working properly but when i using theme app extension is not working and below error given

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoIjI.png

how can i solve this error ?